# How would I get the specific object in json stringify output?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Can anyone help me on how to get the specific object in json?

i just want to sum up all the 3 in the stringify ouput.

```js
var arr_question = [{"$1z_1":3,"$2o_1":"Question 1."},{"$1z_1":3,"$2o_1":"Question2."},{"$1z_1":3,"$2o_1":"Question3."}];

console.log("output: "+arr_question.$1z_1);
console.log("arrays: "+arr_question)
```

Comment: please, provide the expected output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a forEach to iterate over the array and add the value of each object in the array to a previously declared "total"variable which is then the total of all the values.

```js
var arr_question = [{"$1z_1":3,"$2o_1":"Question 1."},{"$1z_1":3,"$2o_1":"Question2."},{"$1z_1":3,"$2o_1":"Question3."}];

var total = 0;
arr_question.forEach(function(obj){
  total += obj.$1z_1;
 })

console.log("output: " + total); // gives "output: 9"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an array of objects. You need to loop through the array, access the attribute and add them up. One option is to use `reduce` method:

```js
var arr_question = [{"$1z_1":3,"$2o_1":"Question 1."},{"$1z_1":3,"$2o_1":"Question2."},{"$1z_1":3,"$2o_1":"Question3."}];

console.log(
  "output: " +
  arr_question.reduce((sum, obj) => sum + obj.$1z_1, 0)
);
```